# Info about PHP Forms

Tags: php, forms, save, backend, autosave

This isn't so much a programming question so much as me just trying to wrap my head around whats going on behind the scenes.

When a user submits content via a php form what exactly happens?

I'm trying to understand how exactly submission data from a form gets saved so that its their for others to see. Take reddit (or even this site) for example, users fill out a form hit submit and their post is there for everyone to see forever. Does this happen no matter what? or is there more code that needs to be added. If it does happen automatically, is the data lost if the server goes offline? how is that data deleted? etc etc

Thanks for the help in advance

EDIT: I guess a better question is how exactly does POST work.

Comment: There is no such thing as a PHP form, if a form is submitted, depending on the method (GET or POST, AJAX or regular request) it'll be sent to the server as URL params, postfields, or as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` (if you're submitting files)

Comment: I think your question is more "how does PHP handle (HTML) forms?", am I correct?

Comment: You guys understood what I am asking. Php and forms, how does it retain the data for later use.

Answer (score 0):

This is a POST example. Please try to find a tutorial to learn PHP.

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="yourName">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit your name">
</form>

<?php
    // This is a PHP comment

    // We check if the POST is made
    if(isset($_POST['yourName'])){
        // We store the POST-variable in a usual variable
        $variableWithName = $_POST['yourName'];

        // Print out the name
        echo "Your name is ".$variableWithName;
    }
```

Comment: The link from @Shad is a perfect example, begin with that.

Comment: Im not trying to learn php. I know how to write php. What I'm getting at is theory behind how sites like this are created. Is form data sent via post method saved to the server automatically so it can be called later or do you have to do something with it. If it is, how is that data deleted? If the server is reset is that data lost? things like that.

Comment: Nothing is automatically.. After the POST, you need to get the variables using PHP, and validate (if you want to). Then open a connection to the database and use MySQL to do an `INSERT`. Once again, use [this link](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-processing.html) and follow the example.

Comment: Here is a great example of what I am talking about http://demos.gravitywiz.com/simple-post-creation-with-gravity-forms/
User fills out a form and submits it. If you notice the url changes and you can use a different browser/computer to access that page you just created. So the data isnt stored in cookies but its stored somewhere. Im asking how exactly is that done.

Right but from what I know about SQL is that it contains data like money and names not entire text fields like paragraphs.

Comment: The data is stored in a database, which you talk to by using MySQL